# Run Apple Hardware Test on Mac without SuperDrive

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, macbook, macbook-pro

I suspect the hard disk in my Mid-2009 Macbook Pro is about to die. I am having unusual problems saving from Dreamweaver CS6 and Xcode 5 where it will simply not let me save, and then refuse to Quit Properly since it knows I have an unsaved file. After a Force Quit I am unable to use the Apple → Shut Down menu.

I have rebooted into Disk Utility and repaired the disk and disk permissions, both successfully, but the problem still happens.

I want to try the Hardware tests that came with my computer, and I DO have the disk, but the SuperDrive in my computer makes an odd clicking sound when I try to insert the disk and immediately ejects it. I've tried cleaning the drive with compressed air but if there's something physical inside I've been unable to clear it.

I have access to a second identical computer which I could conceivably use as a remote disk drive, but I'm under the impression that this isn't possible with my model of MBP.

**How do I run the Hardware Tests if I can't use my SuperDrive?**

Answer (score 0):

First get SMART Utility for OS X http://www.volitans-software.com/smart_utility.php and use that to check your drive to see if it's about to fail.

Not sure if this will work but put the DVD (I think it's actually a CD) in the other identical Mac. Then Target Disk Boot that system and connect it to your problem Mac. Then see if you can do the hardware test boot. Your problem Mac may be able to see the CD in the other machine and boot to it.

You might review http:// support.apple.com/kb/ht1509 and try the options there also. Some Macs have the hardware test on the internal drive. Which would be a problem if the drive is actually failing.

If those don't work then you may be able to use disk utility to clone the DVD/CD to a USB stick and boot to that. See https:/ /www.youtube.com/watch?v=wh4iHJyL7AU
When you boot the machine hold down the 'option' key to see if you can select the USB drive. The H key may also work.